# How to determine whether or not an objects contains a property that points to a specific reference?

Tags: javascript, object, reference

Given these two objects:

```
var object1 = {
    a: function() {},
    b: function() {},
    c: function() {}
};

var object2 = {
    d: function() {},
    e: function() {},
    f: function() {}
};
```

Here we have two objects each containing 3 properties which are function objects (or, to be precise, references to function objects).

Let's say that `f` is a reference to one of those 6 function objects. (It was declared like so: `var f = object2.e;` or `var f = object1.c;`.)

How can I determine whether or not the reference `f` is among the 3 references/properties of `object1`?

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you can do is to iterate over the object's properties:

```
var pointsToObject1 = false;

for(var prop in object1) {
    // maybe call hasOwnProperty but I don't think it is necessary here.
    if(f === object1[prop]) {
        pointsToObject1 = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

`f` is not really pointing to a property of one of the objects. It is more like both, `f` and the property, point to the same value/object.

Comment: Hm, I really hope that ES5 has a built-in function for this.

Comment: @Sime Vidas: Afaik it doesn't.

Comment: King - So something like `object1[f] === f` wouldn't work? Or `!object1[f]`? Why?

Comment: @Jared Farrish: Because the *value* of `f` is a *function*, not a string. It contains the *value* of a property, not its *name*. If you wanted to use `object[f]`, `f` had to be `'a'`, `'b'` or `'c'`.

Answer (score 0):

So this is my current solution (based on @Felix's answer):

```
function isIn(r, o) {
    for (var p in o) {
        if ( o.hasOwnProperty(p) ) {
            if ( o[p] === r ) return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

And then:

```
var f = object1.c;
```

and:

```
isIn(f, object1) // alerts "true"
isIn(f, object2) // alters "false"
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/W3Lub/

What do you think? I find it hard to believe that no browser or library offers this feature?!